# Expansion confusion with expected values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

Edited:
The question provided that $e[(W-\mu)^3] =10$, $E(W^3) = 4$, where W is a random variable (no clarifications on whether it was discrete or continuous) and they were asking whether or not it was possible for $\mu$ to be 2.
What I think the answer did, was expanded the brackets of $(W-\mu)^3$ to get the first line.

I don't understand how they got to the second line though, specifically $3\mu^3$ after expanding the first line. Specially, how $3W\mu^2$ is converted to $3\mu^3$. Where did the $E$ and $W$ go?
[image]

Comment: I suppose $\mu = E[W]$ by definition here, but all we can do is guess, since you haven't provided any [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: Right, apologies. I added more context now, so hopefully that helps?

Comment: It still doesn't clarify what the connection between $\mu$ and $W$ is, so that's something that's probably understood in some bigger context. Where did you encounter this question? In some textbook? If so, which textbook?

Comment: It's called an introduction to Mathematical statistics and it's application 5th edition by Larsen and Marx.

Comment: I only thing that I can think off was this formula:$\mu_r^\prime=E\left[\left(Y-\mu\right)^r\right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\left(y-\mu\right)^r\cdot f_ydy}$ which is for the $r^{th}$ moment  of y around the mean or since it's cubed, I thought it would also relate to this too: $ \gamma_1=\frac{E\left[\left(Y-\mu\right)^3\right]}{\sigma^3}$ which shows the skewness of the function

Comment: btw, it's from a section called higher moments under section 3.6 if you're really curious

Comment: OK, good. I don't have that book, but now maybe someone who is familiar with it will be able to answer.

Comment: Presumably $E[3 W\mu^2-\mu^3]=3\mu E[W]-\mu^3= 3\mu^3-\mu^=2\mu^3$

Comment: Perhaps you can also say $-3E[W^2]\mu = -3\sigma^2-3\mu^3$ so $E[(W-\mu)^3]=E[W^3]-3\sigma^2\mu-\mu^3$ so to have $E[(W-\mu)^3]=10$ and  $E[W^3]=4$ and $\sigma^2\ge 0$ you need $\mu \le -\sqrt[3]{6}\approx -1.817$